# Infinite do loop issue

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Just to preface this question, I am a couple weeks new to Fortran and I have run into an infinite do loop error when running the actual program.

I am 99% sure that the infinite sequence is coming from the do loop, but I thought I should ask just to be sure. I am not sure what part of the do loop is causing the infinite do loop but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
implicit none
   
   ! Declare variables - Add variables as necessary (integer only!)
   ! M will store the encoding matrix, MInv will store its inverse
   ! Decoded_message will store the decoded message
   integer :: M(2,2), MInv(2,2), Determinant, a, b, c, d, detM, i, v(:,:), ascIIcode(:,:)
   allocatable :: v, ascIIcode
   character*32 :: Decoded_Message
   
   ! open data file and read in the encoding matrix
   open(42,file='Data3.txt')
   
   read(42,*) M(1,1), M(1,2)
   read(42,*) M(2,1), M(2,2)
   
   ! Invert the encoding matrix and store it in MInv

   detM  = determinant(M)

   MInv(1,1) = +detM *M(2,2)
   MInv(1,2) = -detM *M(2,1)
   MInv(2,1) = -detM *M(1,2)
   MInv(2,2) = +detM *M(1,1)
   
   
   ! Processing steps required:
       
   ! Read from the file in 2 numbers at a time and store in a vector array
       
       
       
       do i = 2, 31
       
       allocate (v(2,1), ascIIcode(2,1))
       
       read(42,*) v(1,1)
       read(42,*) v(2,1)
       
   ! decode the 2 numbers read in (1) by multiplying Minv by the vector array from (1)
       
       ascIIcode(1,1) = ((MInv(1,1)*v(1,1))+(MInv(1,2)*v(2,1)))
       ascIIcode(2,1) = ((MInv(2,1)*v(1,1))+(MInv(2,2)*v(2,1)))
       
   ! Insert the result from (2) into the character string Decoded_Message. To concatinate 
       
      Decoded_Message = char(ascIIcode(1,1))//char(ascIIcode(2,1))

   ! Use a loop that advances in steps of 2 and goes to 31 
       
       deallocate (v)
       deallocate (ascIIcode)
       
       end do 
       
   ! print results.
       
   print*, Decoded_Message
   
   ! close files
   close(42)

end program Decode


integer function Determinant(M)

   ! This function computes the determinant of matices of size 2 or 3
   ! M is the matrix for which the determinant is calculated (square matrix only)
   ! n is the number of rows or columns in M  

    implicit none
    
    integer :: M(2,2), a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, Det
    
    do
    
    a = M(1,1)
    b = M(1,2)
    c = M(2,1)
    d = M(2,2)
    
    Det = (a*d)-(b*c)
    
    end do

end function Determinant
```

Comment: If you want to diagnose why a program is hanging, you can either use a debugger or put in `print` statements to see what's happening.

Comment: You seem to know that DOs are for looping (rather than simply a command "do the following thing"), so can you explain what you think the `do; ...; end do` in `determinant` means?  (Single line form used for the comment, it's really spread over several lines without semicolons.)  That's your infinite loop, but I struggle to see why you'd think it to be anything else.

Comment: Neither of your loops (the loop `do i=2,31` in the main program and the infinite loop `do` in the function `Determinant`) appear to serve any purpose. You're not using the index `i`, so the loop in the main program is just trying to do the same thing `30` times. And then the loop in `Determinant` is just calculating the same determinant over and over again, an infinite number of times.

Comment: If I completely remove the do loop in the determinant function shouldn't that fix the problem? @francescalus

Comment: If you remove the `do` and the `end do` from the function (and as veryreverie suggests, the loop in the main program is also "useless") that will indeed solve your infinite loop problem. I can't comment on whether you have any other problems, though.

Comment: Alright, I have the infinite loop problem solved. How would I go about looping the main program so that I decode everything. I tried using do i = 2, 31 but it loops until the file runs out. When I remove the do loop, it runs properly and decodes just one of the letters as expected, but how would I get it to loop and decode more than just one letter? @francescalus

Comment: Sorry, the `do i = 2, 31` isn't useless, because you have that read statement.  What is "useless" is that you do nothing with the results in each loop.  You probably want `Decoded_Message (....) = ` (where this `(....)` is the part you need to work out) inside that loop to assign substrings based on the loop index.  If you search for questions about substring assignment you should find more detail.

Comment: Alright, thank you everyone for the help!!! @everyone